# Automatic reference of figures in normal text

Tags: tables, floats, cross-referencing

I am a new user of latex and using with texniccenter. As I am working on my thesis. As I have to add lot of tables and figures. I have to give reference to these figures and tables in my text. is there a way to automatically way to include the reference number of figures/tables. OR every time manually I have to write by myself? For example: In reference to table(x.a), abc abc abc....

Thanks

Comment: use `\caption{my table\label{foo}}`  in the `table` environment and   `see table \ref{foo}` in the text.

Answer (score 2):

Very basic usage

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\caption{Caption}
\label{tab:ExampleTable}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\hline
AAA & BBB   & CCC   \\
\hline
111 & 222   & 333   \\
444 & 555   & 666   \\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

Some text. As seen in Table~\ref{tab:ExampleTable} bla bla bla.

\end{document}
```